# Qt Creator isn't parsing include files properly and displays lots of errors

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator

Qt Creator is not parsing the include files in my project properly and gives a lot of errors in the IDE, including errors like `main.cpp:14:5: error: unknown type name 'QApplication'`. However, my project compiles perfectly fine. I am getting tired of all these supposed errors and am wondering if there is any way to fix this issue.

My .pro file looks like this:

```
QT += core gui widgets
# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    klocktimer.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    klockmainwindow.cpp \
    chronometer.cpp

TRANSLATIONS += \
    klock_en_US.ts \
    klock_es_MX.ts

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    klocktimer.h \
    klockmainwindow.h \
    chronometer.h
```

I had a hunch from a few days ago (I forget exactly how I got this hunch) that `stddef.h` was causing the problem. So I added `#include <stddef.h>` to my main.cpp, and Qt Creator gave the error:

```
/home/loren/code/klock/main.cpp:12: error: 'stddef.h' file not found
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:42: to match this '{'
```

where the '{' is the beginning { in namespace std.

Comment: Can you show your `.pro` file?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Did you try to add current version of Qt?

Comment: No, I did not do that.

Comment: So let's try it

Comment: Well, let's clarify first what you mean. Are you saying to upgrade the installed version of Qt?

Comment: No, just try to write in `.pro` file your current version of Qt. `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): QT += widgets`

Comment: And maybe config of version of C++. `CONFIG += c++14`

Comment: That didn't work. Please read my edits to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somebody on the Qt forums told me to go to the Help Menu > About Plugins > Disable the ClangCodeModel plugin. This required a restart of Qt Creator, but it fixed my problem.

Comment: Coming back several years later, the problem is now fixed and I prefer having ClangCodeModel enabled for C++20 syntax support.